# Why is my stack only adding one element and then it deletes it?

Tags: java, stack

I already debugged the code and found, that it adds the fist element (Stack size = 1)
but when trying to add the next element, the stack size jumps back to 0

I think the problem is in public void convert.

```
public void convert(int N) {
    this.N = N;
    int binary[] = new int[10];
    int index = 0;
    while (N > 0) {
        binary[index++] = N % 2;
        N = N / 2;
    }
    for (int x = index - 1; x >= 0; x--) { 
        this.binStack.push(binary[x]);        //Here is the Problem
    }
}
```

---

This is the whole code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Dec2Bin {
    public Stack<Integer> binStack;  // We make it public to modify it in our tests.
    private int N;

    /**
     * Constructor of an empty object. Use method {@code convert()} to convert a number.
     */
    public Dec2Bin() {
        binStack = new Stack<>();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number that is converted as {@code int}.
     *
     * @return the converted number
     */
    public int getN() {
        return N;
    }

    /**
     * Converts the given number into binary format, with each digit being represented in a
     * stack of {@code int}.
     *
     * @param N the number that is to be converted.
     */
    public void convert(int N) {
        // TODO implement this method
        this.N = N;
        int binary[] = new int[10];
        int index = 0;
        while (N > 0) {
            binary[index++] = N % 2;
            N = N / 2;
        }
        for (int x = index - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            this.binStack.push(binary[x]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the digits that are stored in {@code binStack} as a string. To is the binary format of the
     * converted number.
     * For testing purpose, we require that the function works also, if the variable {@code binStack} is
     * modified externally.
     *
     * @return a string representation of the number in binary format.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Caution: Stack.toString() does NOT respect stack order. Do not use it.
        // TODO implement this method
        String finalBinär = new String();
        for (int y = 0; y < binStack.size(); y++){
            String binär = Integer.toString(binStack.pop());
            String prevBinär = new String();
            finalBinär = prevBinär.concat(binär);
        }
        return finalBinär;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dec2Bin dec2bin = new Dec2Bin();
        dec2bin.convert(50);
        System.out.println("Die Zahl " + dec2bin.getN() + " in Binärdarstellung: " + dec2bin);
        // Do it another time to demonstrate that toString does not erase the binStack.
        System.out.println("Die Zahl " + dec2bin.getN() + " in Binärdarstellung: " + dec2bin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code or using logging to see if you can find the issue?

Comment: What's the implementation of `binStack` Is it java stack or your implementation?

Comment: What is `this.binStack` ?

Comment: I can send you the whole code:

Comment: but binStack is just my Stack

Comment: Your `toString()` method destroys the `binStack`. When stepping through your code with a debugger the debugger probably calls `toString()` after each step and therefore the stack will never be more than one element deep during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
´´´
import java.util.Stack;

public class Dec2Bin {
    public Stack<Integer> binStack;  // We make it public to modify it in our tests.
    private int N;

    /**
     * Constructor of an empty object. Use method {@code convert()} to convert a number.
     */
    public Dec2Bin() {
        binStack = new Stack<>();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number that is converted as {@code int}.
     *
     * @return the converted number
     */
    public int getN() {
        return N;
    }

    /**
     * Converts the given number into binary format, with each digit being represented in a
     * stack of {@code int}.
     *
     * @param N the number that is to be converted.
     */
    public void convert(int N) {
        // TODO implement this method
        this.N = N;
        int binary[] = new int[10];
        int index = 0;
        while (N > 0) {
            binary[index++] = N % 2;
            N = N / 2;
        }
        for (int x = index - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            this.binStack.push(binary[x]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the digits that are stored in {@code binStack} as a string. To is the binary format of the
     * converted number.
     * For testing purpose, we require that the function works also, if the variable {@code binStack} is
     * modified externally.
     *
     * @return a string representation of the number in binary format.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Caution: Stack.toString() does NOT respect stack order. Do not use it.
        // TODO implement this method
        String finalBinär = new String();
        for (int y = 0; y < binStack.size(); y++){
            String binär = Integer.toString(binStack.pop());
            String prevBinär = new String();
            finalBinär = prevBinär.concat(binär);
        }
        return finalBinär;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dec2Bin dec2bin = new Dec2Bin();
        dec2bin.convert(50);
        System.out.println("Die Zahl " + dec2bin.getN() + " in Binärdarstellung: " + dec2bin);
        // Do it another time to demonstrate that toString does not erase the binStack.
        System.out.println("Die Zahl " + dec2bin.getN() + " in Binärdarstellung: " + dec2bin);
    }
}

´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `toString()` method has at least two problems:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // Caution: Stack.toString() does NOT respect stack order. Do not use it.
    // TODO implement this method
    String finalBinär = new String();
    for (int y = 0; y < binStack.size(); y++){   // <1>
        String binär = Integer.toString(binStack.pop());  // <2>
        String prevBinär = new String();
        finalBinär = prevBinär.concat(binär);  // <3>
    }
    return finalBinär;
}
```

Lines <1> and <2>: during the for loop `y` is incremented on line <1>. At the same time the stack size decreases because on line <2> you remove elements from the stack with `binStack.pop()`.

That means that you will only get about half the digits. (For example, if `binStack.size()` was 6 at the start: after 3 runs through the loop `y == 3` and `binStack.size() == 3`, so your loop will terminate.)

Line <3> means that no matter what was in the `binStack`, your result will only ever contain **one** binary digit: that line (together with the previous line) has the same effect as `finalBinär = ""+binär;`, which effectively means: `finalBinär = binär;`